# overridePendingTransition is deprecated, how do i do?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated

There is an animation playing when i finish a child activity or when the main one resume, im not sure which event is triggering it but i would like to replace it. Im targeting api level 34 with a min level of 28.

Im currently using

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
val anim = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
     applicationContext,
     R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.none
).toBundle()
startActivity(intent, anim)
```

I want to play an animation starting an activity but this did not help when I try to resume a parent activity or finish a child activity (again idk in which of these two cases the animation happens)

ChatGPT gave me some "solutions" with startAnimation on the rootView but nothing happens (and it also dont understand the word deprecated so its impossible to correct itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting API 34 , you have to use **`overrideActivityTransition`** , here is the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overrideActivityTransition(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to how to use it .

Comment: 'Call requires API level 34 (current min is 28)'. If I just want to fix ```overridePendingTransition(0, 0)```, what should I do?

Comment: @Krahmal check the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` value, if its 34 use `overrideActivityTransition` else use `overridePendingTransition`

Comment: What about with `finish()`?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below step this is how we do pending transition now.

```html
val enterAnim = R.anim.activity_bottom_in
val exitAnim = R.anim.activity_stay
// Create a bundle for animation options
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(requireContext(), enterAnim, exitAnim)
yourActivityLauncher.launch(getActivityIntent(), options)
```